Find the plane passing through $A$ and tangent with a sphere $(S)$ such that the distance between $B$ and this plane is greatest.

In the $Oxyz$ space, consider point $A(0;8;2)$ and the sphere $(S): (x-5)^2 + (y+3)^2 + (z-7)^2 = 72$ and point $B(9;-7;23)$. $(P)$ is the plane passing through $A$ and tangent with $(S)$ such that the distance from $B$ to $(P)$ is greatest. Find a normal vector of $(P).$

I was able to obtain the correct answer, but I struggled to show it rigorously. I also thought that my approach might not be optimal. I hope to receive advice to make my solution more rigorous and hear alternative approaches if available. Here's the outline of my solution:
Let $I$ be the center of the sphere. Consider the plane $(IAB)$ (illustrated below). Let $(C)$ be the image of $(S)$ on $(IAB) \implies (C)$ is a circle with the same radius as $(S).$
Let $AM$ and $AN$ be tangents of (C) from A $(M, N \in (C),$ and $M$ and $B$ are on the same side with respect to $IA$).
$K = MN \cap IA.$
(The following paragraph is what I found less rigorous and sounds a bit like "my visualization suggests that...")
Consider the plane passing through $AM$ and perpendicular to $(IAB).$ $AM$ is the intersection line of this plane and $(IAB).$ Let $H \in AM$ such that $BH ⊥ AM. \implies$ $H$ is the image of $B$ on this plane. I imagined that if we rotate this plane in keeping with the condition that it passes through $A$ and is tangent with $(S),$ the distance $d$ between $B$ and its image is going to get smaller $(d \leq BH)$ (because the adjacent is smaller or equal to the hypotenuse) until $d = 0$ (i.e. when this plane passes through $B$). After that, if we keep rotating in the same direction, $d$ is going to become larger until it becomes greatest when this plane becomes the plane passing through $AN$ and perpendicular to $(IAB).$ Since the distance from $B$ to $AN$ is greater than the distance from $B$ to $AM$,$(P)$ is the plane passing through $AN$ and perpendicular to $(IAB).$
From this, I find the normal vector $\vec{n_{(IAB)}} = \vec{AB}\times\vec{IA}$ and the direction vector $\vec{u_{MN}} = \vec{n_{(IAB)}}\times\vec{IA}.$
Also, with  $IM = r$ and $IA,$ I could find $IK,$ which allows me to find $K$ through $\vec{KI} = \dfrac{KI}{KA}\vec{KA}.$
Then I could write the equation of line $MN$ (passing through $K$ and having a direction vector $\vec{u_{MN}}$). Then I find the intersections of $MN$ with $(S).$ $N$ is the point farther from $B.$
With $N$, I could find $\vec{IN},$ which is a normal vector of $(P).$ My solution yields $N = (3;-1;-1)$ and $\vec{NI} = (1, -1, 4),$ which matches the key.


Edit : your approach (considering an adequate  slicing plane) is a good one, very "geometric" in its essence.

Here is an alternative solution, analytical,  using Lagrange multipliers (see example here)... and a Computer Algebra System.
Let us first make the following coordinate translation :
$$\begin{cases}X&=&x\\Y&=&y-8\\Z&=&z-2\end{cases}$$
in order that point $A(X=0,Y=0,Z=0)$ becomes the new origin.
Then the coordinates of $B$ and $C$ (the center of the sphere) become resp. :
$$B(X=9,Y=-15,Z=21), \ \ \ C(X=5,Y=-11,Z=5)$$
Let $$aX+bY+cZ=0$$
be the equation of the looked-for plane with normalized normal i.e., with
$$\underbrace{a^2+b^2+c^2}_{f(a,b,c)}=1\tag{1}$$
The distance of $B$ to this plane is known to be
$$\underbrace{9a-15b+21c}_{h(a,b,c)}\tag{2}$$
The distance of $C$ to this very plane is
$$\underbrace{5a-11b+5c}_{h(a,b,c)}=\sqrt{72}\tag{3}$$
Now express that $h$ is maximized when its vector of partial derivatives wrt to $a,b,c$ is a combination of the vectors of the partial derivatives of the two constraints (1) and (3), meaning that there exist $\lambda$ and $\mu$ (Lagrange multipliers) such that :
$$\pmatrix{9\\-15\\21}=\lambda \pmatrix{2a\\2b\\2c} + \mu \pmatrix{5\\-11\\5}\tag{4}$$
Submitting the constraints (1) and (3) and the equations of this system (4) to Wolfram Alpha under the form :
$$\begin{cases}1&=&x^2+y^2+z^2,\\72&=&(5x-11y+5z)^2,\\9&=&2sx+t5,\\-15&=&2sy-t11,\\21&=&2sz+t5 \end{cases}$$
gives 4 solutions for $(x,y,z)$.  The first group of 2 is :
$$x=-\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2}},y=\frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2}},z=-\frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3} \ \text{with anecdotically} \ s=-6 \sqrt{2}, \ t=1$$
and the opposite solution.
Both solutions are proportional to the solution $(1,-1,4)$ you have found (please note that we haven't to come back to the original coordinates, because a plain coordinate translation has no impact on vectors).
The second group of solutions is :
$$x=-\frac{7}{19 \sqrt{2}},y=\frac{-23}{19 \sqrt{2}},z=-\frac{6 \sqrt{2}}{19}$$
and its opposite, corresponding to the other extrema (the plane minimizing the distance of $B$ to a plane passing through $A$ and tangent to the sphere).

Any comment ?...

Thank you very much for your detailed response. I apologize for my late reply; I didn’t receive any answers initially, so I stopped checking as I also have an upcoming exam. Currently, I only have knowledge of single-variable calculus, so I found it challenging to fully grasp your approach. It seems like something I’ll understand better after I study multivariable calculus in a few months. For now, I just want to express my gratitude for the effort you put into providing such a comprehensive answer.
Thank you!

Drawing an accurate sketch of the sphere and points (see below) can help to find the solution without so many calculations. In fact, it looks like the furthest intersection between line $OB$ and the sphere (point $C$ in the figure) is also a tangency point for the lines through $A$.
Finding the coordinates of $C$ is easy:
$$
C=O+{O-B\over OB}\cdot r=(5,-3,7)+{(-4,4,-16)\over12\sqrt{2}}\cdot6\sqrt2=(3,-1,-1)
$$
and a quick check confirms that $AC\perp OC$, because the scalar product $(O-C)\cdot(A-C)$ vanishes. A normal vector is then $O-C=(2,-2,8)$.
The plane thus found is certainly the one having the largest distance from $B$. In fact, take any other tangency point $T$ on the sphere: the distance between $B$ and the tangent plane at $T$ is not more than $BT$, and $BT$ is not more than $BC$ (as $C$ is the point on the sphere furthest from $B$).


Thank you! This question is actually part of a multiple-choice exam, and we have less than 5 minutes to solve it using only pen, paper, and a basic calculator. So, getting the correct sketch might be challenging under those conditions. However, I really appreciate your answer. It's recently come to my attention that many past exam problems can be solved more quickly through smart guessing and verification. This question is a great example of that approach, so your insight is very helpful!
